# Spatie db-dumper package doesn't recognize mysqldump

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to use [spatie/db-dumper](https://github.com/spatie/db-dumper) but it gives me this error when I try to dump my database

> The dump process failed with exitcode 1 : General error : '"mysqldump"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n

note that I have mysqldump command running perfectly on terminal

so does anyone knows how to solve it?
Thanks!

my code:

```
Route::get('/export',function(){
Spatie\DbDumper\Databases\MySql::create()
    ->setDbName('trello')
    ->setUserName('root')
    ->setPassword('')
    ->dumpToFile('dump.sql');
});
```

Comment: I think it cannot be work in windows. Just use Mac or linux or docker in WSL

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/db-dumper/issues/137